# Connection denied while trying to clone data (XtraBackup) from mysql-master (Kubernetes)

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

Friends, I trying run a replicated Mysql database with the help of XtraBackup and when it gets to the point when the second node tries to clone data from the master, I'm getting the following error **(ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**). This is the point where I get the error:

```
  if [[ -f change_master_to.sql.in ]]; then
            echo "Waiting for mysqld to be ready (accepting connections)"
            until mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=${MYSQL_USER} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} --execute="SHOW DATABASES"; do sleep 1; done
            echo "Initializing replication from clone position"
            mysql -h 127.0.0.1 \
                  -e "$(<change_master_to.sql.in), \
                          MASTER_HOST='mysql-0.mysql', \
                          MASTER_USER='root', \
                          MASTER_PASSWORD='root-password', \
                          MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10; \
                        START SLAVE;" || exit 1
            mv change_master_to.sql.in change_master_to.sql.orig
          fi
```

Since I am passing a password and the error log it's saying the opposite, I think the problem may be somewhere else but I don't know where. Any Ideas?

Here is my complete yml just in case someone wants to take a look at it:

```
  apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          [[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          echo [mysqld] > /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          echo server-id=$((100 + $ordinal)) >> /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          if [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]]; then
            cp /mnt/config-map/master.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          else
            cp /mnt/config-map/slave.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          fi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /mnt/conf.d
        - name: config-map
          mountPath: /mnt/config-map
      - name: clone-mysql
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/xtrabackup:1.0 #bitnami/percona-xtrabackup:8 perconalab/percona-xtrabackup 
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Skip the clone if data already exists.
          [[ -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ]] && exit 0
          # Skip the clone on master (ordinal index 0).
          [[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]] && exit 0
          # Clone data from previous peer.
          ncat --recv-only mysql-$(($ordinal-1)).mysql 3307 | xbstream -x -C /var/lib/mysql
          # Prepare the backup.
          xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/var/lib/mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webservice-secrets
              key: mysql_user
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webservice-secrets
              key: mysql_password
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webservice-secrets
              key:  mysql_root_password
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webservice-secrets
              key: mysql_database
        ports:
        - name: mysql
          containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1Gi
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - "bash" 
            - "-c"
            - "mysql --user=${MYSQL_USER} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} --execute=\"SHOW DATABASES;\""
          initialDelaySeconds: 40
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - "bash" 
            - "-c"
            - "mysql --user=${MYSQL_USER} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} --execute=\"SHOW DATABASES;\""
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 2
      - name: xtrabackup
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/xtrabackup:1.0 #perconalab/percona-xtrabackup
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webservice-secrets
              key: mysql_user
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webservice-secrets
              key: mysql_password
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: webservice-secrets
              key: mysql_root_password
        ports:
        - name: xtrabackup
          containerPort: 3307
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          cd /var/lib/mysql
          if [[ -f xtrabackup_slave_info && "x$(<xtrabackup_slave_info)" != "x" ]]; then
            cat xtrabackup_slave_info | sed -E 's/;$//g' > change_master_to.sql.in
            rm -f xtrabackup_slave_info xtrabackup_binlog_info
          elif [[ -f xtrabackup_binlog_info ]]; then
            [[ `cat xtrabackup_binlog_info` =~ ^(.*?)[[:space:]]+(.*?)$ ]] || exit 1
            rm -f xtrabackup_binlog_info xtrabackup_slave_info
            echo "CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='${BASH_REMATCH[1]}',\
                  MASTER_LOG_POS=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" > change_master_to.sql.in
          fi

          if [[ -f change_master_to.sql.in ]]; then
            echo "Waiting for mysqld to be ready (accepting connections)"
            until mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user='root' --password='root-password' --execute='SHOW DATABASES'; do sleep 1; done
            echo "Initializing replication from clone position"
            mysql -h 127.0.0.1 \
                  -e "$(<change_master_to.sql.in), \
                          MASTER_HOST='mysql-0.mysql', \
                          MASTER_USER='root', \
                          MASTER_PASSWORD='root-password', \
                          MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10; \
                          START SLAVE;" || exit 1
            mv change_master_to.sql.in change_master_to.sql.orig
          fi
          exec ncat --listen --keep-open --send-only --max-conns=1 3307 -c \
            "xtrabackup --backup --slave-info --stream=xbstream --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --password=root-password"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
      volumes:
      - name: conf
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config-map
        configMap:
          name: mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

In below statement or code, you are trying to connect mysql without username and password.

> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 
> -e "$(<change_master_to.sql.in), 
> MASTER_HOST='mysql-0.mysql', 
> MASTER_USER='root', 
> MASTER_PASSWORD='root-password', 
> MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10; 
> START SLAVE;" || exit 1

Try below once instead of above one so you can say, we need to use username and password to connect local mysql.

> mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user='root' --password='root-password' 
> -e "$(<change_master_to.sql.in), 
> MASTER_HOST='mysql-0.mysql', 
> MASTER_USER='root', 
> MASTER_PASSWORD='root-password', 
> MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10; 
> START SLAVE;" || exit 1